# Why do we use concrete clases in java?

Tags: java

**why do we use concrete classes in java?**
I've tried a lot to search a proper reason,but all i found is comparison between abstract class and concrete class.
i want to know in what kind of conditions we need to create concrete classes.

Comment: how can you create an object for an abstract class in java?

Comment: Concrete class are the classes with full implementations. Concrete classes are used to implement the responsibilities decided for the class. Secondly @Shriram correctly mentioned that we can't have objects for abstract classes

Comment: *I've tried a lot to search a proper reason* - I really think that you haven't done enough research :)

Comment: A normal java class which can't have abstract methods is known as concrete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract classes are meant to be used as the base for other classes to be derived.  The concrete class we derive is expected to provide an implementation for each method not implemented in the base (abstract) class.

We have to use concrete classes and not abstract classes, because if you could instantiate abstract classes, there would be the possibility of calling a method that has not been implemented yet.

Here's an example. Let's say we have the following Shape class:

```
public abstract class Shape {

    private Point center;

    public Shape(Point p) {
       this.center = p;
    }

    public abstract void draw();

    public void erase() {
        setColor(backgroundColor);
        draw();
        setColor(foregroundColor);
    }
}
```

In this example, we don't know how to draw the Shape, since we don't know exactly what the shape looks like!  We know that if we draw with the background color over the path used to draw (in the erase method), then we will be able to change it back to the background color.  Once we do know the actual shape's pattern, then we can **extend** it in a new concrete class.

So why is this used instead of inheritance?  The main reason (in this example) is because we want to use the draw method in the erase method.  If we did not have the abstract method and only had erase, we wouldn't be able to call the draw method, affecting our program design, which is quite simple and useful.

Comment: thanks!pls post any example !